# javascript variable in ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is my javascript code.

```
    $(\"img.agree\").click(function()
    {
    var follow_id = $(this).attr(\"id\");
    var user_id = $(\"img.user_id\").attr(\"id\");

    $.ajax({
     type: \"POST\",
     url: \"/sys/follow.php\",
     data: { 'follow_id': + follow_id, 'user_id': + user_id },
     success: function(html){}
    });

    $(\"img.agree\"+follow_id).hide();
    $(\"img.notagree\"+follow_id).css('display','inline-block');
    });

    $(\"img.notagree\").click(function()
    {
    var follow_id = $(this).attr(\"id\");
    var user_id = $(\"img.user_id\").attr(\"id\");

    $.ajax({
     type: \"POST\",
     url: \"/sys/dontfollow.php\",
     data: { 'follow_id': + follow_id, 'user_id': + user_id },
     success: function(html){}
    });

    $(\"img.notagree\"+follow_id).hide();
    $(\"img.agree\"+follow_id).css('display','inline-block');
    });
```

I use unique string after class='agree$string' or class='notagree$string' to be ajax request one and specific, not to send requests equal to number of all img tags. But it wont work. The problem i think is in +follow_id or something like that.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to understand what you are doing. Please post the PHP code you are outputting this JavaScript from so we can see the complete context.

Comment: Why are you escaping the quotes?

Comment: @Blowsie Assume the quotes are escaped because this JS is inside a PHP string.

Comment: Don't `echo` your JavaScript with PHP. You see how difficult it is to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered moving this out into a javascript file?  I don't see any point in generating this with PHP since there are no PHP variables being used.  Also, it seems as if your HTML may look something like this.

```
<html>
<img id="1" class="agree1" src"" />
<img id="1" class="notagree1" src"" />
</html>
```

If that is the case you really shouldn't have different elements with the same ID.
I think something like this.

```
<html>
<img id="agree1" class="agree" src"" />
<img id="notagree1" class="notagree"  src"" />
</html>
```

The corresponding JS would be:

```
$("img.agree").click(function()
    {
        var follow_id = /\d/.exec(this.id); //parse out the number you are looking for with a regex
        var user_id = $("img.user_id").attr("id");

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/sys/follow.php",
             data: { 'follow_id': + follow_id, 'user_id': + user_id },
             success: function(html){}
        });

        $("#agree"+follow_id).hide();
        $("#notagree"+follow_id).css('display','inline-block');
    });

$("img.notagree").click(function()
    {
        var follow_id = /\d/.exec(this.id); //parse out the number you are looking for with a regex
        var user_id = $("img.user_id").attr("id");

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/sys/dontfollow.php",
             data: { 'follow_id': + follow_id, 'user_id': + user_id },
             success: function(html){}
        });

        $("#notagree"+follow_id).hide();
        $("#agree"+follow_id).css('display','inline-block');
    });
```

And again, I advocate removing this from the PHP as well